# bootstrap strange bug when recompiling assets

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

i have this strange bug where...

in my application.js file i have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```

if i do

```
 RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile
```

my bootstrap drop down stops working. however, if i remove the require twitter/bootstrap and hit save on my editor, and then refresh the page on my local machine. it works again.

i dont understand why. this jquery/bootstrap loading has been an issue for weeks. recompiling my assets break it. it works if i recompiled it, but then remove it and refresh the browser

UPDATE.

my css is using custom.css.scss. theres nothing special in there except

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

at the top of the file.

ive reverted back to scss instead of less, and my application.js looks like...

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

on my development machine, the weird bug above occurs but in production everything seems to work fine

Comment: hi Crystal, can your clarify your question further? How does your CSS look?

Comment: hi tim, its strange because on my production, things seem to work. but on development it has that weird issue

Comment: can i you isolate the problem? i've included this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Q7p/25/. Can you modify the HTML on this to match your code so I can understand better.

Comment: i modified the html on the jsfiddle. it looks a bit weird cause i have ruby code in there but...thats pretty much my <nav> section.
thanks for helping = ) i much appreciate it. do you think it has anything to do with...the loading of the asset pipeline? cache? or something specific to my development machine? cause it works fine on my production as long as the code looks like above (in my post under the update section)

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not a ruby programmer. But perhaps just comparing the development vs. production HTML source codes, or even better comparing the CSS rules that were actually applied to the `<nav>` section upon compiling is all you'll need. Do you use Chrome? If so, hold down the "control" key and click on top of the `<nav>`. This will open the developer tools showing you the element you just clicked on. From there you can check the `<nav>`'s CSS that were computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i fixed it. i had to do...

```
rake assets:clean
```

something was probably corrupt and also...

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

in my development.rb